# Apostrophe inside magepage.csv makes SyntaxError

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, localisation

I'm confronting 2 Magento eCommerce, one is 1.9.2.1 and the other 1.9.3.2, they both have this translation inside Mage_Page.csv

```
 "- Use the %s, %s buttons to select year","- Usa i bottoni %s, %s per selezionare l\'anno"
```

Problem is with 1.9.2.1 I get this error on web console:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

What could be the difference between the two?